# Al usar el CONCAT, me sale error diciendo" La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto"

Tags: c#, mysql, windows-forms, datatable, concat

Resulta que cargos datos a un `DataTable` de la siguiente forma:

```
private void cargarempresas()
{
    dt_hogar = new DataTable();
    String sql = "SELECT CAST(CONCAT(nombre,'-',apellido)AS CHAR) AS nombre,fechacreacion FROM hogar";
    conexion.conectar();
    datos = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conexion.con);
    conexion.cerrar();
    datos.Fill(dt_hogar);
    var source = new BindingSource();
    source.DataSource = dt_hogar ;
    Dtgempresas.DataSource = source;
}
```

Y actualizo de la siguiente forma el `DataTable`:

```
private void btnActualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmdbder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(datos);
    datos.Update(dt_hogar);
}
```

Pero sale el siguiente error:

> La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.

Para mostrar el nombre y apellido en una sola columna, uso el `CONCAT`, pero resulta, que al usarlo, me sale el error al actualizar, ¿alguna idea mostrar el nombre y apellido junto, sin necesidad de usar el `CONCAT` para que no me salga error al actualizar.

Comment: String sql = "SELECT nombre, fechacreacion FROM hogar". 
Si en la consulta pones el siguiente código también te marca error?

Answer (score 1):

Ejecuta:

```
SELECT CONCAT(nombre,'-',apellido) AS nombre, fechacreacion FROM hogar
```

Nótese que no tiene el `CAST`, probablemente algún resultado viene `NULL` y te genera problemas.